# Ошибка vk.exceptions.VkAuthError: OAuth2 authorization error

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всем привет! Перерыл весь гугл, все вопросы, не могу найти причину...
Получаю ошибку авторизации:
vk.exceptions.VkAuthError: OAuth2 authorization error

Код:

```
import vk
vk.logger.setLevel('DEBUG')
session = vk.AuthSession(app_id='#', user_login='#', user_password='#')
vk_api = vk.API(session)
```

Логи:

```
2021-05-22 03:09:14,505 vk    mixins:19 DEBUG: AuthMixin.__init__(app_id='№', user_login='№', user_password='№', **kwargs={})
2021-05-22 03:09:14,506 vk    api:24 DEBUG: API.__init__(access_token=None)
2021-05-22 03:09:14,506 vk    api:50 DEBUG: access_token = None
2021-05-22 03:09:14,506 vk    mixins:64 DEBUG: AuthMixin.get_access_token()
2021-05-22 03:09:14,506 vk    utils:77 DEBUG: Request: GET https://m.vk.com, params=None, data=None
2021-05-22 03:09:14,620 vk    utils:79 DEBUG: Response: 200 https://m.vk.com/
2021-05-22 03:09:14,620 vk    utils:77 DEBUG: Request: POST https://login.vk.com/?act=login&to=&ip_h=8f77134d0a1cfb85d3&lg_h=be7f147a3be5be1ab9&role=pda&utf8=1&_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fm.vk.com, params=None, data={'email': '№', 'pass': '№'}
2021-05-22 03:09:15,230 vk    utils:79 DEBUG: Response: 200 https://m.vk.com/feed
2021-05-22 03:09:15,230 vk    mixins:92 DEBUG: Cookies: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie h=1 for .login.vk.com/>, <Cookie l=14523717 for .login.vk.com/>, <Cookie p=fe66005ea995b32496204424e75ccfaf8eb9be5d8172c8e75c48ce77b for .login.vk.com/>, <Cookie s=1 for .login.vk.com/>, <Cookie remixaudio_show_alert_today=0 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixff=0 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixlang=0 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixmdv=76vumRj0F04mTCQY for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixsid=2e7f30b9261e3ee4af4db9d5f7ea9428d43e0cab4 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixstid=1507081874_JsvHfWLhruuQ7Zs7TUGraeT for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixtmr_login=1 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixua=-1%7C-1%7C30909314173 for .vk.com/>]>
2021-05-22 03:09:15,230 vk    utils:77 DEBUG: Request: POST https://oauth.vk.com/authorize, params=None, data={'client_id': '№', 'display': 'mobile', 'response_type': 'token', 'scope': 'offline', 'v': '5.28'}
2021-05-22 03:09:15,377 vk    utils:79 DEBUG: Response: 200 https://oauth.vk.com/authorize
2021-05-22 03:09:15,377 vk    mixins:127 INFO: Getting permissions
2021-05-22 03:09:15,377 vk    mixins:130 DEBUG: Response form action: https://login.vk.com/?act=grant_access&client_id=№&settings=65536&response_type=token&group_ids=&token_type=0&v=5.28&display=mobile&ip_h=8f77134d0a85d3&hash=1621642155_e056eebde735&https=1&state=&redirect_uri=
2021-05-22 03:09:15,377 vk    utils:77 DEBUG: Request: GET https://login.vk.com/?act=grant_access&client_id=№&settings=65536&response_type=token&group_ids=&token_type=0&v=5.28&display=mobile&ip_h=8f77134d0a13&hash=1621642155_e056ee735&https=1&state=&redirect_uri=, params=None, data=None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\VK-pars\vk_pars_project\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    session = vk.AuthSession(app_id='#', user_login='#', user_password='#')
  File "D:\Programming\VK-pars\venv\lib\site-packages\vk\mixins.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.access_token = self.get_access_token()
  File "D:\Programming\VK-pars\venv\lib\site-packages\vk\mixins.py", line 75, in get_access_token
    raise VkAuthError('OAuth2 authorization error')
vk.exceptions.VkAuthError: OAuth2 authorization error
2021-05-22 03:09:15,431 vk    utils:79 DEBUG: Response: 200 https://oauth.vk.com/auth_redirect?app_id=#&authorize_url=https%253A%252F%252Foauth.vk.com%252Fblank.html%2523access_token%253D5a933.....463%2526expires_in%253D0%2526user_id%253D14523717&redirect_hash=b4516....5bb958
```

Я пробовал:
Создавать новое приложение, Перелогиниваться, менять пароль, csope и v указывать, провобавл формировать запрос с этими же данными в браузере, всё без ошибок. Что может быть? Приложение не заблокировано, создано standartnoe. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы используете данные вместо `'#'`?

Comment: Со времени вашего вопроса прошло много времени, для библиотеки вышла версия [3.0](https://vk.readthedocs.io/en/3.0). Ваша проблема всё так же воспроизводится? Если да, то подскажите, какой app_id вы используете?